# UITabBarController's TabBar items title are not visible in Xib

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have UITabBarController which has 3 UITabBarItems . I have set the title for all these items, these items are tappable & receiving the event but not showing the title.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your view hierarchy, I can see that there are different viewcontrollers. You should try setting the tab bar title and it's image programmatically for each controller.

`viewcontroller.tabBarItem.title = "Dash"
 viewcontroller.tabBarItem.image = UIImage.init(named: "imageName")
 viewcontroller.tabBarItem.selectedImage= UIImage.init(named: "imageName")`

Comment: Thanks for replying , i have did something like this